# Javascript tracing events

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

Is there a way to trace the events that are triggered at a given moment?

I'm thinking in a script like [Visual Event 2](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2)

I'd like to have all the events with its linked function in the log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what's wrong with Visual Event ?

Comment: I don't get the trace of events triggered.